# Send a variable or array from javascript to asp.net (using ajax)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, function

I would to know how to pass variables. I have a variable in javascript but I dont know how to pass it to a textbox. I have read it is so easy using ajax, but I dont know how to use it. I believed this was just for not to have reload. Well, then how do I do it? I read I must use get and post, but I dont know how to use it.. for example I have the code:

```
function guardar() {
    var completo = "hola mundo";
}
```

How do I get the variable `completo` to pass it in a textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, then using jQuery, you'd say:

```
$("#myTextboxId").val(completo);
```

And that would set the textbox who's id is `myTextboxId` to the value of your variable `completo`

Comment: or document.getElementById('myTextboxId').value = completo; for regular javascript

Comment: where do i write this code? inside a function in javascrit? or where o do i write it?\n ..

Comment: You put that code wherever you want.  You've got a variable you want to write to a textbox.  If you have jQuery, use the line I gave you, if not, use the line davidsleeps gave you.

Comment: i put it inside a function (javascript) and this gets a bug

Comment: i dont know to use jquery .. do i must to paste it in a jquery?